# Precompute scale of svg paths to given widths and heights

Tags: javascript, svg

Lets say I have an arbitrary svg with paths:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <path d="...." />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="...." />
  </g>
</svg>
```

For each path, I have calculated the exact **width** and **height** bbox values (in pixels) that I want them to be scaled down to on render. These values are correct and (when needed) will preserve the aspect ratio of the paths.
With no change to scaling (`scale(1)`), the default size of the paths are very big (hundreds of pixels), covering a lot of the svg.

I have figured out that once I know the original width and height values of a given path at scale(1), then I can divide **width** by the original width and **height** by the original height to get the scale value I am looking for. This method, however, requires rendering the path first at scale(1) to determine the original dimensions.

Is there a way to calculate the `transform: scale(x)` value that yeilds a path of size **width** and **height** before rendering the svg? Or are there other beneficial scaling methods or factors at play that I am missing? I am using jsx/React components for rendering the svg although this is probably inconsequential.

---

### Update

The [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/) library solves this issue another way by scaling the path strings themselves instead of using transforms. This is not as efficient as vanilla js but still quite fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the paths to visibility: hidden and then show them only after they are scaled. You can then render them at scale(1), calculate the scale you want and have no visible artifacts affecting your work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manipulating the viewBox attribute on the parent SVG element?

[viewBox reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

[Excellent in-depth article regarding SVG coordinate system](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)

A simple example:

```
<svg id="my-svg">
  <g style="background:white;">
    <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#003" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

And then the following javascript as a simplistic example:

```
let svg = document.getElementById("my-svg");

svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0, 0, 100, 80");
```

Comment: I can see how this would work to scale one path, but what about if I have multiple paths in my svg and each of the paths have their own dimensions that I want them to be scaled to? I have updated the question to reflect this. Thanks for the links by the way, I will give them a read!

Comment: Oh yes, your new requirements do change things as the viewBox attribute would affect everything within the SVG.